# What's the correct way to set focus on a form field in Angular Material? ViewChild (with MatInput or ElementRef) is not working for me

Tags: angular, angular-material, focus

### Overview:

I'm using mat-accordion which contains 3 mat-expansion-panel elements.  Each expansion panel has a form field, and I'd like to set focus on the relevant form field whenever its associated panel is opened.  It's meant to be used with an optical barcode scanner. The workflow for the end user looks like this:

1. Click the link and arrive at this page of the app.
2. Panel 1 of the accordion is open and Ticket Barcode field automatically gets initial focus.
3. Scan first barcode; scanner is configured to return a CR at the end of the data.
4. The CR triggers panel 2 to open, and the Wristband Barcode field should get focus.
5. Scan second barcode.
6. The CR triggers panel 3 to open, which displays data associated to the scanned barcodes.
7. Click "Confirm" to submit the scanned barcodes and reset the form.

Our UX requirements dictate that steps 2 through 6 should not require the user to use the keyboard or mouse--just the barcode scanner. That means we need to programmatically handle the focus on those fields. There are other elements of this interface, but I've stripped out the non-relevant logic from the code below.

### ng --version

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.23
Node: 12.14.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.23
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.23
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.23
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.23
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.23
@schematics/angular               8.3.23
@schematics/update                0.803.23
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

### scan.component.html

```
<mat-accordion class="redemption-accordion">

  <!-- panel 1 -->
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step===1" (opened)="setStep(1)" hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        1. Scan Ticket
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="42px" gutterSize="3px">
      <mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
          <mat-label>Ticket Barcode</mat-label>
          <input #ticketBarcodeField matInput name="ticketBarcodeField" [(ngModel)]="ticketBarcode" (keyup.enter)="onTicketEnter()" required>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>

    <mat-action-row>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">Next <mat-icon>arrow_forward</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-action-row>
  </mat-expansion-panel>

  <!-- panel 2 -->
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step===2" (opened)="setStep(2)" hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        2. Scan Wristband
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="42px" gutterSize="3px">
      <mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
          <mat-label>Wristband Barcode</mat-label>
          <input #wristbandBarcodeField matInput name="wristbandBarcodeField" [(ngModel)]="wristbandBarcode" (keyup.enter)="onWristbandEnter()" required>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>

    <mat-action-row>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="prevStep()"><mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon> Back</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">Next <mat-icon>arrow_forward</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-action-row>
  </mat-expansion-panel>

  <!-- Panel 3 -->
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step===3" (opened)="setStep(3)" hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        3. Confirm
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-action-row>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="prevStep()"><mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon> Back</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="resetForm()"><mat-icon>clear</mat-icon> Cancel</button>
      <button mat-raised-button class="greenButton" [disabled]="!canSubmit" (click)="submitTransaction()">Confirm <mat-icon>arrow_forward</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-action-row>

  </mat-expansion-panel>

</mat-accordion>
```

### scan.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from  '@angular/core';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material/input';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scan',
  templateUrl: './scan.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scan.component.scss']
})
export class WristbandSwapComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private canSubmit: boolean;
  private step: number;
  private ticketBarcode: string;
  private wristbandBarcode: string;

  @ViewChild('ticketBarcodeField', {read:MatInput, static:false}) public ticketBarcodeField: MatInput;
  @ViewChild('wristbandBarcodeField', {read:ElementRef, static:false}) private wristbandBarcodeField: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private spinner:NgxSpinnerService
  ) {
    this.canSubmit = false;
    this.step = 0;
    this.ticketBarcode = '';
    this.wristbandBarcode = '';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("Running ngAfterViewInit...");
    // components should be defined at this point
    console.log("this.ticketBarcodeField:", this.ticketBarcodeField);
    console.log("this.wristbandBarcodeField:", this.wristbandBarcodeField);
    // make sure panel 1 is expanded
    this.setStep(1);
  }

  // triggered when a CR is detected in the ticketBarcode field
  onTicketEnter() {
    this.spinner.show('primary');
    // Logic goes here to check the scanned ticket barcode
    this.spinner.hide('primary');
    this.nextStep();
  }

  // triggered when a CR is detected in the wristbandBarcode field
  onWristbandEnter() {
    this.spinner.show('primary');
    // Logic goes here to check the scanned wristband barcode
    this.spinner.hide('primary');
    this.nextStep();
  }

  // triggered when an accordion panel is explicitly opened
  setStep(index: number) {
    console.log("Setting step to " + index);
    this.step = index;
    this.doFocus();
  }

  // triggered by "next" arrows on the accordion
  nextStep() {
    console.log("Called nextStep...");
    this.step++;
    this.doFocus();
  }

  // triggered by "back" arrows on the accordion
  prevStep() {
    console.log("Called prevStep...");
    this.step--;
    this.doFocus();
  }

  // triggered by "Cancel" button
  resetForm() {
    this.ticketBarcode = '';
    this.wristbandBarcode = '';
    this.ticket = null;
    this.setStep(1);
  }

  // When an accordion panel is open, make sure its field has focus
  doFocus() {
    if (this.step === 1) {
      console.log("Setting focus on ticketBarcodeField");
      // MatInput provides a focus method
      this.ticketBarcodeField.focus();
    } else if (this.step === 2) {
      console.log("Setting focus on wristbandBarcodeField");
      // the nativeElement attribute of ElementRef provides the focus method
      this.wristbandBarcodeField.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

  // triggered when the Confirm button is clicked
  submitTransaction() {
    console.log("called submitTransaction");
    // logic goes here to handle the scanned barcode values
  }

}
```

### console output

Here's what I see in my console when the page loads.

```
Running ngAfterViewInit...
this.ticketBarcodeField: MatInput {_defaultErrorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher, _parentForm: null, _parentFormGroup: null, ngControl: NgModel, errorState: false, …}
this.wristbandBarcodeField: ElementRef {nativeElement: input#mat-input-4.mat-input-element.mat-form-field-autofill-control.cdk-text-field-autofill-monitor…}
Setting step to 1
Setting focus on ticketBarcodeField
```

And when I open my second expansion panel:

```
Setting step to 2
Setting focus on wristbandBarcodeField
```

But neither form field ever gets focus.
My Google searches led me to believe that MatInput is the preferred method, along with "this.myField.focus()", but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please tell me the correct way to set focus on that field? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try wrapping your focus calls in `setTimeout`. Sometimes these kinds of things are due to event cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've changed those lines of code to look like this:
`setTimeout(() => this.ticketBarcodeField.focus());`
The field still never gained focus.  So I tried a different syntax.
`setTimeout(function(){ this.ticketBarcodeField.focus(); },100);`
That finally got it working.